# Replacing a character from a file by Perl script

Tags: perl

I am trying to replace a windows line ending character `\r\n` with linux style line ending character `\n` in a text file using a perl script. What I have written in the script is as the following:

```
system("perl -pi -e s/\r\n/\n/g input.txt");
```

And the resulting warning is:

> Substitution pattern not terminated at -e line 1

I'd glad if I learn where this command is wrong.

Edit: When I used:

```
system("perl -pi -e 's/\r\n/\n/g' words.txt");
```

I got this warning:

> Can't find string terminator "'" anywhere before EOF at -e line 1

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Separate the args for your system call.  That will help you avoid needing to use the proper quoting and escaping:

```
system('perl', '-i', '-pe', 's/\r\n/\n/g', 'input.txt');
```

However, I'd recommend just doing this with `$INPLACE_EDIT`:

```
my $file = 'input.txt';

local @ARGV = $file;
local $^I = '';
while (<>) {
    s/\R/\n/;
    print;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have applied the change and there is a string terminator error now.

Comment: Also need to escape the backslashes.

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -p -i -e 's/\r\n/\n/g' input.txt
```

You are missing `''` in your regex. hence the error `Substitution pattern not terminated at -e line 1`

Comment: Thanks for the response, I got another warning when I hade the change as in the edited question

Answer (score 1):

you are running the script on Windows, so you have to change the simple quotes and double quotes, and define the extension of the `-i` flag.

```
system('perl -i.bak -p -e "s/\r\n/\n/g" words.txt');
```

Comment: Thanks, the Warning is gone, but currently \r\n characters still remain in the text file.